# Android + WebService em Plataforma Cloud

Tags: java, android, cloud, openshift

Fala galera...

Bem, preciso muito criar um projeto. Um sistema WEB e Android.

Mas tem que ser Cloud e gratuito de preferencia.

Pesquisei e iniciei um projeto usando o OpenShift. Instalei um plugin no Eclipse e mandei bala em JAVA. Consegui até criar algumas páginas WEB, mas tive problemas de compatibilidade com o Axis2, etc ao tentar disponibilizar serviços. O maior problema é que não encontrei tutoriais completos sobre o assunto.

Enfim amigos, preciso muito de ajuda (a cabeça está pra explodir). Qual o melhor serviço cloud pra que eu possa rodar meu webService de modo que ele também esteja disponível para Android? (Obs: pode se em outra linguagem: Ruby on Rails, JAVA, PHP, etc)

Se você concorda que é o OpenShift, então me da um help aí pra que eu possa disponibilizar meus serviços.

Desde já agradeço sua atenção. Preciso esfriar minha cabeça um pouco...

Comment: Olá, Jedaias! Sua pergunta foi suspensa porque os usuários da comunidade consideraram que não é possível dar uma resposta objetiva. Não existe um serviço que seja melhor e qualquer plataforma consegue integrar com Android. Posso lhe dizer que os OpenShift e Heroku são boas soluções que possuem um plano inicial gratuito. Fora isso, sugiro que você poste perguntas mais específicas sobre os erros ou problemas que está enfrentando na sua implementação, pois o [pt.so] não é adequado para tutoriais ou para perguntas muito amplas ou que sejam baseadas apenas em opiniões. Abraço!

Answer (score 1):

Usa a plataforma [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) que você pode criar até 5 aplicações free, lá você pode usar python, java, ruby, php, Nodejs para o seu problema, a melhor opção é criar uma web app REST, que basicamente é uma aplicação web que retorna um json ou xml de acordo com a requisição.

Algumas referências sobre REST - [wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST), [InfoQ](http://www.infoq.com/br/articles/rest-introduction)

Alguns frameworks já vem com isso pronto é o caso do Rails para Ruby, Spring para Java e Flask-RESTful para Python

Comment: Opa, obrigado meu amigo. Testando agora aqui!

Comment: Qualquer é só comentar e se dica foi boa não esquece de um ok.

Comment: Preciso de 15 pontos para poder votar a favor, rsrsrs...